# Swift Charts - Multiple AreaMark gap and not continuous

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, charts

I have a Swift Charts graph with areas of different colors.
The original idea is to be able to select a part of the chart with drag & drop (from: `x` to `y`) and style the selected area differently (with a different color for example).

Here is the code:

```swift
import SwiftUI
import Charts

struct Value: Identifiable {
    var x: String
    var y: Int
    var color: String
    var id: UUID = UUID()
}

struct ContentView: View {
    let data: [Value] = [
        .init(x: "0", y: 3, color: "red"),
        .init(x: "1", y: 4, color: "red"),
        .init(x: "2", y: 5, color: "red"),
        .init(x: "3", y: 8, color: "red"),
        .init(x: "4", y: 6, color: "red"),
        .init(x: "5", y: 4, color: "red"),
        .init(x: "6", y: 6, color: "blue"),
        .init(x: "7", y: 8, color: "blue"),
        .init(x: "8", y: 10, color: "blue"),
        .init(x: "9", y: 8, color: "blue"),
        .init(x: "10", y: 5, color: "blue"),
        .init(x: "11", y: 7, color: "blue"),
        .init(x: "12", y: 10, color: "blue")
    ]
    
    var body: some View {
        
        
        VStack {
            Chart(data) { v in
                LineMark(
                    x: .value("x", v.x),
                    y: .value("y", v.y)
                )
                .interpolationMethod(.catmullRom)
                .foregroundStyle(Color.black)
                
                AreaMark(
                    x: .value("x", v.x),
                    y: .value("y", v.y)
                )
                .interpolationMethod(.catmullRom)
                .foregroundStyle(by: .value("area", v.color))
            }
            .chartForegroundStyleScale([
                "red": Color.red,
                "blue": Color.blue,
                "green": Color.green
            ])
            
        }
        .frame(maxHeight: 300)

    }
}
```

It produces the following output:

[image: Simulator output]

Is there anyway I can remove the gap between the two areas? Like between `5` and `6` it would be filled with half red and half blue as a continuous area? Thanks!

Update:
If i try to insert an additional `.init(x: "5", y: 4, color: "blue")`, the graph is all messed up.

[image]

Comment: Hi @Sweeper :) Yes ^^ I implemented the way you suggested with a Plottable date with string primitive. I have the same problem with my real project. Is it due to the fact that my X are strings and not numbers?

Comment: No it's not because of that. How about preprocessing the data and add an extra `.init(x: "5", y: 4, color: "blue")`?

Comment: I tried but it messed up the chart (see my edit).

Comment: The default behaviour stacks your area charts. Add `stacking: .unstacked` when you create the `AreaMark`.

Comment: The original feature I tried to implement, is the ability to select an area on the chart. For example, from 4 to 7 and have the area between this two coordinates  colored differently. I did it with 3 `area styles`: before / selected / after (tried with just two, but it was connecting the line between the area before the selected area and the one after the selected area.

Comment: And how is that relevant to this question?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256764/discussion-between-vincent-and-sweeper).